# Dictionary: TypeError: 'bool'/'nonetype object' not iterable when looping in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For the following dictionary,

```
a1 = {'a2':{'name':'mic\xa0\xa0', 'age':'12\xa0\xa0', 'college':True, 'contact':''},
        'a3':{'name':'sen\xa0\xa0', 'age':'23\xa0\xa0','college':True,'contact':''}}
```

When looping on dictionary and performing some action getting `bool` object not iterable, if remove the boolean field(`college`) from dictionary then error is coming for empty filed(`nonetype`(`contact`) object not iterable)

```
def t1():
    a4 = {k : 
    {k2: ''.join([i if 32 < ord(i) < 126 else " " for i in v2])
    for k2, v2 in v.items()} for k, v in a1.items()
    }
    return a4

a5 = t1()
print(a5)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `v.items()` gives the inner dictionaries (e.g. `{'name':'mic\xa0\xa0', ...}`.  So, each `v2` is each value in that dictionary, one of which is a `bool` type.  Thus, when you try to iterate over the `bool` type with `for i in v2` you get the error.

Comment: @anmaxvl removing the non-ASCII-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a small change to check if `v2` is a string using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance). If it is a string, then iterate and do your operation. Otherwise, return it unchanged.

Example:

```
def t1():
    a4 = {
        k : {
            k2: ''.join([i if 32 < ord(i) < 126 else " " for i in v2]) 
            if isinstance(v2, str) else v2 for k2, v2 in v.items()  
        } 
        for k, v in a1.items()
    }
    return a4

a5 = t1()

print(a5)
```

Output:

```
{
  "a3": {
    "age": "23  ", 
    "contact": "", 
    "college": True, 
    "name": "sen  "
  }, 
  "a2": {
    "age": "12  ", 
    "contact": "", 
    "college": True, 
    "name": "mic  "
  }
}
```

You may also want to add in a `.strip()` to the result of the `join()` in order to remove leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: but boolean filed is getting excluded..?

Comment: My mistake @Prashant. I fixed it, please check the edit.